# How to specify 3 cultures in Blazor wasm, Out of 3 only two work

Tags: localization, blazor-webassembly

I use localstorage to store/retrieve culture names and change the current culture according to it.

I have 3 resource files. since I use .net 6 I have this config in program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("fa"), new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("ar") };

//CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ar");
//CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ar");
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("fa");
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;   
});
```

Unfortunately "ar" is not working and the other two culture work. But when I uncomment the commented line "ar" works and "en" not.

So how to specify all 3 cultures correctly so that all work?

Comment: Did you use the 4 char code instead of 2 for language specification? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-7.0#CultureNames

Comment: no i use 2 chars